# Git Extensions: How to un "sync" with a submodule

Tags: git-submodules, git-extensions

In Git Extensions, I accidentially right clicked and "sync"ed with a submodule, now any current branch I am on is "sync"ed-- so **Submodulefoo [mycurrentbranch]** in the left hand branch tree ..it was very easy to sync, not so clear how to unsync. Thanks in advance.

[whatever branch I checkout is syncing with submodule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OksPf.png)
[synced to new branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC9xm.png)

Comment: Why do you need to un-sync?

Comment: Hi! Despite reading about sync a few times I'm not exactly clear on what it does. I am not the author nor do I have access to the submodule..I'd just like for unsync to be an option, Because I found that sync is very easy to accidentally do.

Comment: This makes no sense. Sync means to ensure a submodule is at the same commit as it should be for the the superproject's HEAD commit. When a user moves around the superproject (i.e. checks out different commits) it is easy to have a submodule at a incorrect commit.